# Table1 ID is auto increment and i also want to store the information from table 2 against that auto generated ID

Tags: mysql, update, insert, alter-table

This table has an auto increment ID on back end.

```
"INSERT INTO `test`.`personal_info`
    (`username`, `email`,`password`)
VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')";
```

This was for signing up of one page. Following is the page code which I want to link to upper table.

```
"UPDATE `test`.`personal_info` 
WHERE Id='10' (`Name`, `Mid_name`, `Last_name`,`d_o_b`) 
VALUES ('$Name', '$Mid_name', '$Last_name','$date')";
```

Comment: The second statement is not valid syntax. Have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html That aside, I have no idea what the problem is. There's no question in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update field ID and set to 10?

Some sample:

```
UPDATE test.personal_info
SET ID = '10'
WHERE db1.table1 = db2.table2
```

OR

```
 UPDATE test.personal_info
 SET ID = '10'
 ON <DB.TABLE>
 JOIN TABLE1.FIELD = DB.TABLE2.FIELD
```